# criteria where all elements are removed the wrong value is displayed

Tags: java

I've tried changing around signs and re writing code to fix the following "criteria" but it does would and i still fail the fulfill the criteria:

> index 10 out of bounds for length 10
>
> The list should have size 0 after remove all elements, but it say size 10, ==> expected <0> but is <10>

*MyArrayList.java*

```
public class MyArrayList {

    private int[] array;
    private int current;
    public MyArrayList(int size) {
       array=new int[size];
       current = 0;
    }
 
     public MyArrayList(){
     setArraySize(10);
    }
   
 
 
    public void setArraySize(int size){
        array=new int[size];
        current=0;
    }
 
 
    public void add(int value) {
     array[current] = value;
     current++;
 
    }
 
    public int get(int position){ 
        int value = 0;
        if(position >= 0 && position < current) {
            value = array[position];
          }
          return value;
    }
 
    public void set(int position, int value) {
        if(position > 0 && position <= current) 
            array[position] = value;
 
    }
 
    public int size() {
        return current;
    }
 
 
    public void remove(int position) {
      int index = position;
      if(position > 0 && position <= current) {
      for(int i = index; i < current - 1; i++) {
           array[i] = array[i+1];
      }
       current--;
      }
 
    }
 
    public int[] toArray() {
        int[] newArray = new int[current];
        for(int i = 0; i <= current -1; i++) {
          newArray[i] = array[i];
        }
        return newArray;
    }
 
 
    public void replace(int oldValue, int newValue) {
        for(int i = 0; i < current; i++) {
            if(array[i] == oldValue) {
                 array[i] = newValue;
                 break;
               }
        }
    }
 
 
    public boolean contains(int value) {
        for(int i = 0; i < current; i++) {
            if(array[i]==value){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
 
 
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (current == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
 
 
    public void clear() {
        current = 0;
    }
 
}
```

*Runner.java*

```
public class Runner {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
                MyArrayList mylist = new MyArrayList(10);
                mylist.add(10);
                mylist.add(15);
                mylist.add(10);
                mylist.add(35);
                mylist.add(50);
                mylist.add(10);
 
                System.out.println("IsEmpty should be false: " + mylist.isEmpty());
                System.out.println("Size should be 6: " + mylist.size());
                System.out.println("Element at position 3 should be 10: " + mylist.get(3));
 
                // set 3 position to 20
                mylist.set(3, 20);
                System.out.println("Element at position 3 should be 20 now: " + mylist.get(3));
 
                // remove 3rd element which is 20
                mylist.remove(3);
                System.out.println("Element at position 3 should be 35 now: " + mylist.get(3));
                System.out.println("Size should be 5: " + mylist.size());
 
                // try removing last element
                mylist.remove(5);
                System.out.println("Element at position 5 should be 0: " + mylist.get(5));
                System.out.println("Size should be 4: " + mylist.size());
 
                // replace first occurrence of 10 to 9
                mylist.replace(10, 9);
                System.out.println("Element at position 1 should be 9 now: " + mylist.get(1));
 
                System.out.println("contains(45) should be false: " + mylist.contains(45));
                System.out.println("contains(35) should be true: " + mylist.contains(35));
 
                System.out.println("Array should be: 9 15 35 50");
                int[] array = mylist.toArray();
                for(int element: array) {
                        System.out.print(element + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
 
                mylist.clear();
                System.out.println("IsEmpty should be true: " + mylist.isEmpty());
                System.out.println("Size should be 0: " + mylist.size());
        }
 
}
```

Comment: @Abra this is like a course exercise where marks are given by criteria. These "index 10 out of bounds for length 10" and  "The list should have size 0 after remove all elements, but it say size 10, ==> expected <0> but is <10>" is not being met so i don't get full marks, can you help me fulfill these requirments

Comment: The code itself works, but doesn't adhere to the above requirements/criteria @Abra

Comment: @Abra
List of instructions: (the first image is criteria for this code, second is the "error/criteria" i was talking about

https://imgur.com/a/1jGx83S

Comment: If your free @Abra can you show me how to do it properly please. i've been at this for 16+ hrs. Can you link the correct code on paste bin or smth. Sorry if this sounds arrogant or smth, i really don't get it and would appreciate it if you can take some of your time to help me please. Sorry if i can't repay your kindness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your corrected code. Compare it with yours.

```java
public class MyArrayList {
    private static final int  INCREASE = 10;

    private int[] array;
    private int current;

    public MyArrayList(int size) {
        array = new int[size];
        current = 0;
    }

    public MyArrayList() {
        this(INCREASE);
    }

    public void add(int value) {
        if (current == array.length) {
            ensureCapacity();
        }
        array[current++] = value;
    }

    public int get(int position) {
        int value = 0;
        if (position >= 0 && position < current) {
            value = array[position];
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void set(int position, int value) {
        if (position >= 0 && position < current) {
            array[position] = value;
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return current;
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        int index = position;
        if (position >= 0 && position < current) {
            for (int i = index; i < current - 1; i++) {
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
            }
            current--;
        }
    }

    public int[] toArray() {
        int[] newArray = new int[current];
        for (int i = 0; i <= current - 1; i++) {
            newArray[i] = array[i];
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    public void replace(int oldValue, int newValue) {
        for (int i = 0; i < current; i++) {
            if (array[i] == oldValue) {
                array[i] = newValue;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(int value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < current; i++) {
            if (array[i] == value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return current == 0;
    }

    public void clear() {
        current = 0;
    }

    private void ensureCapacity() {
        int[] newArray = new int[array.length + INCREASE];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, array.length);
        array = newArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyArrayList mylist = new MyArrayList(10);
        mylist.add(10);
        mylist.add(15);
        mylist.add(10);
        mylist.add(35);
        mylist.add(50);
        mylist.add(10);

        System.out.println("IsEmpty should be false: " + mylist.isEmpty());
        System.out.println("Size should be 6: " + mylist.size());
        System.out.println("Element at index 3 should be 35: " + mylist.get(3));

        // set 3 index to 20
        mylist.set(3, 20);
        System.out.println("Element at index 3 should be 20 now: " + mylist.get(3));

        // remove 3rd element which is 20
        mylist.remove(3);
        System.out.println("Element at index 3 should be 50 now: " + mylist.get(3));
        System.out.println("Size should be 5: " + mylist.size());

        // try removing last element
        mylist.remove(4);
        System.out.println("Element at index 4 should be 0: " + mylist.get(4));
        System.out.println("Size should be 4: " + mylist.size());

        // replace first occurrence of 10 to 9
        mylist.replace(10, 9);
        System.out.println("Element at index 0 should be 9 now: " + mylist.get(0));

        System.out.println("contains(45) should be false: " + mylist.contains(45));
        System.out.println("contains(15) should be true: " + mylist.contains(15));

        System.out.println("Array should be: 9 15 10 50");
        int[] array = mylist.toArray();
        for (int element : array) {
            System.out.print(element + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        mylist.clear();
        System.out.println("IsEmpty should be true: " + mylist.isEmpty());
        System.out.println("Size should be 0: " + mylist.size());
    }
}
```

Here is the output when running the above code. Also compare it with yours.

```
IsEmpty should be false: false
Size should be 6: 6
Element at index 3 should be 35: 35
Element at index 3 should be 20 now: 20
Element at index 3 should be 50 now: 50
Size should be 5: 5
Element at index 4 should be 0: 0
Size should be 4: 4
Element at index 0 should be 9 now: 9
contains(45) should be false: false
contains(15) should be true: true
Array should be: 9 15 10 50
9 15 10 50 
IsEmpty should be true: true
Size should be 0: 0
```

In method `main` (in the above code), an instance of class `MyArrayList` is created and the following six elements are added.

```
10
15
10
35
50
10
```

- The index of the first element is 0 (zero).
- The index of the last element is 5.
- The list contains six elements, hence its size is 6.

The code in method `main` then tests the methods of class `MyArrayList`.

- The element at index 3 is 35. (Note: not *position* but *index*.)
- Replacing the element at index 3 with 20 means the list now contains the following

```
10
15
10
20
50
10
```

- Removing the element at index 3 means the list now contains the following

```
10
15
10
50
10
```

Now the list has five elements, hence the size is now 5. The index of the first element is still 0 (zero). The index of the last element is 4, i.e. one less than the size. The element at index 3 in the list is now 50.

- Removing the last element now means removing the element at index 4 (since the size of the list is 5). Now the size of the list is 4 (since we removed the last element) and the index of the last element is now 3. So according to the instructions, calling method `get(4)` should return 0 (zero) since 4 is larger than the index of the last element. In other words, there is no index 4 in a list whose size is 4.
- Calling `replace(10, 9)` means the first element in the list, i.e. the element at index 0 (zero), is now 9. Hence the list now contains the following

```
9
15
10
50
```

Finally, I added method `ensureCapacity`. In java, an array is a fixed size. The instructions do not say that you cannot add more elements than the size of the array. So if the default size is 10 (ten) and you want to add eleven elements, you need to create a larger array. Hence method `ensureCapacity` creates a new, larger array and copies the values from class member `array` to the new array. Then class member `array` is assigned the value of `newArray`.